# Cloud Run deploy fails (gcloud run deploy) with error gcloud crashed (KeyError): 'images'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build, docker-image

gcloud cli crashed after successfull image build right before deploy command with error:

```
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8347067Z Building Container....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8351347Z failed
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8352361Z Deployment failed
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8839076Z ERROR: gcloud crashed (KeyError): 'images'
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8839690Z 
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8840175Z If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8840690Z   gcloud feedback
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8840875Z 
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8841213Z To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
2022-09-19T06:05:37.8847153Z   gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

UPDATED:
There were enabled kaniko cache in the separate build script under the user account who run deploy script on the same build machine:

```
# Enable Kaniko cache to speed up the build
gcloud config set builds/use_kaniko True
gcloud config set builds/kaniko_cache_ttl 672 # 4 weeks
```

And, it leads to conflict between `gcloud run deploy --source` and `gcloud run deploy --image` commands.

Definitely, it is a bug in the Cloud SDK.

Workaround: All commands `gcloud run deploy` which runs under the same user and the same machine should use --image param in case if kaniko cache is enabled. It is not so hard, just need to split the command `gcloud run deploy --source` into two separate command:

1. `gcloud builds submit --tag IMAGE_ID`
2. `gcloud run deploy --image IMAGE_ID`

Comment: Please check this document https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/kaniko-cache#enabling_kaniko_cache_in_your_builds and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html. If you still have this issue observed, please feel free to raise the same on  https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Thanks, this documentation is first what I have read. It is not a blocker at this moment already due to we have found a workaround already. Let me know if you need more information to reproduce it. I am not sure is it bug actually. But the error message in this case should be different, as for me.

Comment: yep, same issue here, reported it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254860725 Disabling Kaniko fixes it. Your workaround works, that's how I used to do it before they advertised --source: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/build-and-deploy-an-app-to-cloud-run-with-a-single-command